# Is this possible with SVG

Tags: svg

I need to retire an ActiveX control that displays a wireframe plot like the attached photo. The data used to draw the plot comes form a text file. The green lines represents the structure of a bridge viewed from the side. The blue, red, and one of the green lines represent the sonar sounding of the river bottom. The bridge structure is made up of a collection of lines an polygons. Each bridge is different so it would be nice to have a collection of objects that I could use to build the SVG representation of the bridge. The Sonar Sounding lines, grid, and axis are basically a line graph. Is this possible using SVG. Can I draw a bridge and then put a graph on top of it?

[image]

Comment: Sure it's possible. Is that all you wanted to know?

Comment: Everything you have here including rotated text labels is quite doable. I'd investigate the use of the vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" attribute to draw the hair lines. It's possible some older browsers might have problems.

Comment: Robert, I have many more questions but I needed to know if SVG is the right technology for the job.

Comment: Robert, I'm mainly a C/C++/C#/ASP.Net developer with average HTML JavaScript experience and for years I have used this site for reference. This is the first time I've posted a question here. Based on my research I was sure SVG was right but I needed reassurance. So now I need some help with application architecture and best practice for getting data from Db to the client to drawing. Do you know of any examples that address a similar problem?

Comment: An SVG-based graphing library such as [D3](https://d3js.org/) may prove useful to you.  There are also several other JS libraries that will help you to build SVG diagrams, if you want to do the graphing yourself.